# PHP page creates too much load, server overloaded page?

Tags: php, load

Ive got a busy site which keeps taking down the server.

What is an easy piece of PHP code that can look at the server load, if the server load variable set to say 2, then when load is above two - It will produce a page for the user - Server overloaded.

Does anyone know where to find such an easy piece of code?

Comment: Pfff that's a very broad question, don't really get the up-vote. So in terms of load, which load should that be? Requests per minute, apache's data transfers, mysql load, etc etc. This is such a big topic that the an _easy script_ you so much want, can be very easy if you narrow your questions to exactly _what_ to measure.

Comment: Server load, avg server load. e.g 2.00 load.

Comment: That shouldn't be handled by PHP, end ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will die if the load is above 80%.

However, this is not supported on Windows platforms:

```
<?php
$load = sys_getloadavg();
if ($load[0] > 80) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Too busy, try again later');
    die('Server too busy. Please try again later.');
}
?>
```

Ref. : PHP.net : [sys_getloadavg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php)

Comment: If you have PHP < v5.1.3 you can approximate this behavior by parsing the results from `exec('uptime')`

Comment: The server is still getting overloaded, its strange... people still keep thrashing the one index file.